# Rationale for [dcl.constexpr]p5 in the c++ standard

Tags: c++, function, language-lawyer, constexpr

What is the rationale for [dcl.constexpr]p5 (http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.constexpr#5)?

> For a non-template, non-defaulted constexpr function or a
>   non-template, non-defaulted, non-inheriting constexpr constructor, if
>   no argument values exist such that an invocation of the function or
>   constructor could be an evaluated subexpression of a core constant
>   expression ([expr.const]), or, for a constructor, a constant
>   initializer for some object ([basic.start.init]), the program is
>   ill-formed; no diagnostic required.

If a program violated this rule, declaring the offending function constexpr was useless. So what? Isn't it better to accept useless uses of the decl-specifier constexpr instead of triggering undefined behaviour (by no diagnostics required)? In addition to the problem with undefined behaviour we also have the additional complexity of having the rule [dcl.constexpr]p5 in the standard.

An implementation can still provide useful diagnostic messages in some cases that it is able to detect (warnings by convention). Just like in the following case:

```
int main() { 0; }
```

The expression in main there is well-formed but useless. Some compilers issue a diagnostic message anyway (and they are allowed to) in the form of a warning.

I understand that [dcl.constexpr]p5 cannot require diagnostics, so i'm not asking about that. I'm just asking about why this rule is even in the standard.

Comment: So that the implementation can diagnose a never-constexpr function if it wants, but doesn't have to go out of its way to. Similar to early checking of templates.

Comment: Please include the wording in your question, links may go dead and then the question is not as useful as a reference.

Comment: @T.C Implementations may diagnose anything they want, no special permission needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it's ill-formed is because making it ill-formed allows implementations to reject `constexpr` function definitions that cannot possibly form constant expressions. Rejecting them early means getting more useful diagnostics.

The reason no diagnostic is required is because it may be unrealistic for an implementation to determine that for each and every possible combination of arguments, the result is not a constant expression.

The fact that ill-formed, no diagnostic required, effectively means the same thing as making the behaviour undefined seems to me as if it's unfortunate, but merely picked for lack of a better option. I'd be highly surprised if the intent would actually be to allow any arbitrary run-time behaviour, but there is no concept of "may be diagnosed as an error, but if not, must behave as specified" for any language feature in C++.

Comment: This "may be diagnosed as an error, but if not, must behave as specified" concept can be expessed simply as "non-portable".

Comment: @n.m. The standard could define "non-portable" in such a way. It could define pretty much any term in such a way. But that isn't how "non-portable" is commonly used. The way it's commonly used doesn't say anything about how code behaves on other implementations. It could give an error, or it could do something totally different.

Comment: In response to the first section: Making such programs well-formed, doesn't prevent an implementation from giving useful diagnostics. Diagnostic messages are allowed for well-formed programs. Compilers usually give diagnostics messages for the well-formed program int main() { 0; } and that is fine (i form of a warning). A similar thing could be done here. In response to the second section: Yes I know that. If that rule exists it must be a "no diagnostic required" rule, and that is what concerns me.

Comment: @Supremum That's a fair point. Unfortunately giving useful warnings and then following that by a bunch of useless errors means that people ask here on SO about the useless errors without looking at the warnings, or at least that's the impression I've been left with. :(

Comment: So the possibility of rejecting a program instead of just diagnosing against it is worth introducing undefined behaviour? And remember is it only a possibility for the implementation.

Comment: @Supremum Current real-world implementations do in practice either accept the program with sensible semantics or reject it with an error. Current real-world implementors take reports about bad QoI seriously even if it doesn't affect conformance. Because of that, I can understand the balance weighing in favour of trusting implementors to do the right thing here. But if implementors do start giving such programs radically different behaviour, then my personal opinion would start to shift towards yours.

Comment: So they considered the possibility to reject instead of just diagnose worth the additional complexity in the c++ standard and introduction of undefined behaviour. Personally I don't even think that possibility is even worth the additional complexity of having [dcl.constexpr]p5 in the standard. Now I know at least what they think was worth the extra complexity and undefined behaviour even if I highly disagree.